# Match text strings containing quotation marks which are encoded differently

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, fuzzyjoin

I have two data frames containing the same information.  The first contains a unique identifier.  I would like to user `dplyr::inner_join` to match by title.

Unfortunately, one of the data frames contains {"} to signify a quote and the other simply uses a single quote

For example, I would like to match the two titles shown below.

```
The {"}Level of Readiness{"} for HCV treatment
The 'Level of Readiness' for HCV treatment
```

Comment: Can you use `gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", str)` to remove any non alphanumeric character and join after that?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn them into single quotes using `gsub`, but you need to enclose `{"}` with single quotes and `'` with double quotes. Note that `fixed = TRUE` treats `'{"}'` as a literal string instead of a regular expression:

```
gsub('{"}', "'", 'The {"}Level of Readiness{"} for HCV treatment', fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "The 'Level of Readiness' for HCV treatment"
```

Comment: When I run the code above in R, I get the error below:
Error in gsub("{\"}", "'", "The {\"}Level of Readiness{\"} for HCV treatment") : 
  invalid regular expression '{"}', reason 'Invalid contents of {}'

Comment: @user25494 sorry, I missed the `fixed = TRUE` option. It should work now.